# SQL Query JOIN or IN operator?

Tags: sql, sql-server, logical-operators

I have two tables, 
**PERSON** 
and **FRIENDS**.
FRIENDS has the fields NAME and SURNAME.

A person has N friends.

**I want to retrieve all the PERSONs that have atleast two FRIENDs, one with name ="mark", and the other with name="rocco" and surname ="siffredi".**

Example: if I have a person that has 5 friends, one of them is called mark and no one is called rocco siffredi, no tables are returned.

I was thinking about:

```
SELECT * FROM person p
         JOIN friends AS f ON p.ID=f.personID
WHERE f.name ="mark" AND f IN 
            ( SELECT * from FRIENDS WHERE name="rocco" and surname="siffredi")
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM person p
         JOIN friends AS f1 ON p.ID=f1.personID
         JOIN friends AS f2 ON p.ID=f2.personID
WHERE    f1.name="mark" AND f2.name="rocco" AND f2.surname="siffredi"
```

What is the best way? I mean the fastest way to execute it.
I don't care about readability.
Is there any other way to execute this query?
Ty.

EDIT: added the join on the ID...

Comment: What does "best" mean? For readability I would use `WHERE EXISTS (...name="mark") AND EXISTS (...name.="rocco" AND surname="siffredi")`.

Comment: The FK should be the other way round. If FK is on `Person` table, then each person can have only one friend.

Comment: Edited the FK.
edited the intended"best"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to guess your column names and make up a table:

Use EXISTS:

```
CREATE table FRIENDS(person_id INT, friend_id INT)

go

SELECT * 
FROM person 
WHERE 
  EXISTS
   (SELECT * 
    FROM friends f 
    JOIN person per
    ON f.friend_id = per.id
    WHERE
      per.name ='mark' AND
      person.id = f.person_id) AND
  EXISTS
   (SELECT * 
    FROM friends f 
    JOIN person per
    ON f.friend_id = per.id
    WHERE
      per.name = 'rocco' AND
      per.surname='siffredi' AND
      person.id = f.person_id)
```

Comment: Your second exists will never return anything because per.name can't be Mark and Rocco at the same time.

Comment: @Spock well spotted, I copied and pasted too much, it has been corrected

Comment: what is the difference from my second proposed query?

Comment: @Gaetano you are missing a reference back to the person table. Making you unable to refer to the names of the friends

Comment: I can't refer the names of the friends with the AS on the JOINs?

Comment: not unless you have the friend names in the friends table. I sure hope you don't. You should have a many to many relation from person to friends and back to person

Comment: the friends table has the names O_O

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69129/discussion-between-gaetano-and-t-clausen-dk).

Answer (score 3):

Your schema design isn't very good for what you are trying to do... I would have a Person table as you have, which would also contain a unique identifier called PersonId. I would then have a Friends table which took two fields - Person1Id and Person2Id.

This gives you a couple of important advantages - first of all your system is able to handle more than one bloke called John Smith (because we join on Ids rather than Names...). Secondly, a person's details are only ever recorded in the Person table. One definition of truth...

Comment: I was thinking that the IDs where obviously there. let me edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

With these data as input:

```
INSERT INTO Person VALUES 
(1, 'Bob', 'Smith'),
(2, 'Jim', 'Jones')

INSERT INTO Friends VALUES
(1, 1, 'Mark', 'Tally'),
(2, 1, 'John', 'Smith'),
(3, 1, 'Jack', 'Pollock'),
(4, 2, 'Mark', 'Rush'),
(5, 2, 'Rocco', 'Siffredi'),
(6, 2, 'Mark', 'Bush')
```

you can use this query:

```
SELECT PersonId, COUNT(*) AS NoOfFriends
FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT PersonId, Name,
          Surname = CASE WHEN NAME = 'Mark' THEN NULl
                         ELSE Surname
                    END  
   FROM Friends
   WHERE Name = 'Mark' OR (Name = 'Rocco' AND Surname = 'Siffredi') ) t
GROUP BY PersonId
```

to get the distinct number of required friends per `PersonID`:

```
PersonId    NoOfFriends
------------------------
1           1
2           2
```

You can now join with the above table expression on `PersonId` and filter it by `NoOfFriends`:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM Person AS p
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT PersonId, COUNT(*) AS NoOfFriends
   FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT PersonId, Name,
             Surname = CASE WHEN NAME = 'Mark' THEN NULl
                         ELSE Surname
                       END  
      FROM Friends
      WHERE Name = 'Mark' OR (Name = 'Rocco' AND Surname = 'Siffredi') ) t
   GROUP BY PersonId ) s ON s.PersonId = p.ID 
WHERE s.NoOfFriends = 2
```

so as to get only persons having the required combination of associated friends:

```
ID  Name    Surname
-------------------
2   Jim     Jones
```

P.S. I have completely re-written my answer after @t-clausen.dk's comment.

Comment: it would fail if the person had 2 friends named mark

Comment: @t-clausen.dk You can have a look at my new answer if you like. It think it works ok now, though I'm not sure if it's more efficient than your solution.